# Interface logic when a class has parent/child logic

Tags: c#

I would like to put my interfaces into a separate assembly, but I'm having trouble implementing the interfaces.

```
public interface IModelObject {...} 

public interface IViewmodel 
{
    IModelObject ModelObject { get; }
}

public interface ITreeNodeViewmodel: IViewmodel {...}

public interface ITreeViewmodel 
{
    ITreeNodeViewmodel Root { get; set; }
}
```

Now in the implementation:

```
public class NodeViewmodel:ITreeNodeViewmodel {...}
public class TreeViewmodel:ITreeViewmodel
{
    NodeViewmodel Root { get; set; }

    ITreeNodeViewmodel ITreeViewmodel.Root { get => Root; set => Root = (NodeViewmodel)value; }
    ITreeNodeViewmodel ITreeViewmodel.Root => Root;
}
```

You can see that the design requires that the `TreeViewmodel.Root` should be constrained to the  `NodeViewmodel` type. I can explicitly implement the interface and have one smelly explicit cast in the setter.

Is there a better way to enforce a type constraint on this property and still satisfy the interface?

Comment: You are missing the definition for `NodeTreeItemViewmodel`. Is it just `NodeTreeItemViewmodel : ITreeNodeViewmodel`?

Comment: Oops that should be a `NodeViewmodel`. I will fix.

Answer (score 5):

You can create generic interfaces that extend your other interfaces like so

```cs
public interface ITreeViewmodel<T> where T: ITreeNodeViewmodel 
{
    T Root { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think, this is a good solution. The original approach containing `ITreeNodeViewmodel Root { get; set; }` (without generic) wouldn't work even if covariant return types for interface properties/methods were allowed because the existence of the setter really says: when a class implements this, I can assign any object to `Root` if its class implements `ITreeNodeViewmodel`. The generic approach clearly defines which (potentially more specific) type the `Root` should be assignable to.

Answer (score 1):

There is quite a strong likelihood that you'll end up with this kind of object structure:

```
public interface IModel
{ }

public interface IViewModel<M> : IModel
    where M : IModel
{
    M Model { get; }
}

public interface ITreeNodeViewModel<M> : IViewModel<M>
    where M : IModel
{ }

public interface ITreeViewModel<M, T>
    where M : IModel
    where T : ITreeNodeViewModel<M>
{
    T Root { get; }
}

public class TreeNodeViewModel<M> : ITreeNodeViewModel<M>
    where M : IModel
{
    public M Model { get; private set; }
}

public class TreeViewModel<M, T> : ITreeViewModel<M, T>
    where M : IModel
    where T : ITreeNodeViewModel<M>
{
    public T Root { get; private set; }
}
```

I just thought I'd post it as I think it'll be the natural progression of your object model once you start working with it.

Comment: You are so right =), I was in the middle of implementing this. Can you suggest how to assign `Root` in the constructor of `TreeViewModel`? It seems I might need a `new()` constraint as well...

Comment: Or inherit from TreeViewModel and assign concrete types. This is the way I'm going.

Answer (score 0):

Given the requirements you're working with, your implementation looks good.  If you don't want a "smelly cast", you could try something along the lines of:

```
set
{
   if (value is NodeTreeItemViewmodel goodRoot)
   {
      Root = goodRoot;
   }
   else 
   {
      throw new ArgumentException("Root must be a NodeTreeItemViewmodel 
 instance");
   }
}
```

This takes more code, but will at least give you clearer feedback if something goes wrong.